# MySQL - change time values of one row to match time values of another row of the same table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have several consultants who record their job start/end times. Because they have two-hour minimum fees, I need to make sure that I properly calculate their job times. The problem arises when they have consecutive jobs on the same site, with idle times ranging between 15 to 60 minutes between jobs.

The following is a query result of my sample table ordered by cid, job_date, start_time. For this particular example, all job time entries are for the same day:

```
 id  job_num    cid job_date    start_time           end_time
 19  130513-20  6   05/13/2013  2013-05-13 13:30:00  2013-05-13 16:30:00
 10  130513-10  7   05/13/2013  2013-05-13 11:00:00  2013-05-13 13:00:00
 16  130513-17  13  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 14:45:00  2013-05-13 15:30:00
 15  130513-16  16  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 14:45:00  2013-05-13 16:15:00
 18  130513-19  34  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 11:15:00  2013-05-13 12:15:00
 8   130513-08  44  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 12:00:00  2013-05-13 14:30:00
 6   130513-06  47  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 11:00:00  2013-05-13 12:00:00
 9   130513-09  47  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 12:00:00  2013-05-13 12:30:00
 14  130513-15  47  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 14:30:00  2013-05-13 15:15:00
 3   130513-03  50  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 09:00:00  2013-05-13 10:45:00
 7   130513-07  50  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 11:00:00  2013-05-13 12:00:00
 11  130513-11  50  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 13:00:00  2013-05-13 14:30:00
 17  130513-18  50  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 15:00:00  2013-05-13 16:15:00
 2   130513-02  52  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 09:30:00  2013-05-13 10:30:00
 4   130513-04  52  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 10:30:00  2013-05-13 11:00:00
 5   130513-05  52  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 11:00:00  2013-05-13 13:00:00
 12  130513-12  52  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 14:00:00  2013-05-13 14:45:00
 13  130513-13  52  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 15:00:00  2013-05-13 17:00:00
 20  130513-21  61  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 11:00:00  2013-05-13 12:00:00
 1   130513-01  70  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 14:30:00  2013-05-13 15:15:00
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to update the end_time of a particular row (job_num) so that it is equal to the end_time of the next job_num in the query for the same consultant (cid), but only if the difference (idle time) between the end_time of the first job and the start_time of the following job <= 30 minutes. Basically, I want to add the idle time to the end_time of the first job in the comparison.

For example:

```
 id  job_num    cid job_date    start                end                
 3   130513-03  50  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 09:00:00  2013-05-13 10:45:00  <-- original
 7   130513-07  50  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 11:00:00  2013-05-13 12:00:00 
 11  130513-11  50  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 13:00:00  2013-05-13 14:30:00  <-- original
 17  130513-18  50  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 15:00:00  2013-05-13 16:15:00 
...
 12  130513-12  52  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 14:00:00  2013-05-13 14:45:00  <-- original
 13  130513-13  52  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 15:00:00  2013-05-13 17:00:00
```

become:

```
 3   130513-03  50  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 09:00:00  2013-05-13 11:00:00  <-- changed
 7   130513-07  50  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 11:00:00  2013-05-13 12:00:00 
 11  130513-11  50  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 13:00:00  2013-05-13 15:00:00  <-- changed
 17  130513-18  50  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 15:00:00  2013-05-13 16:15:00 
...
 12  130513-12  52  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 14:00:00  2013-05-13 15:00:00  <-- changed
 13  130513-13  52  05/13/2013  2013-05-13 15:00:00  2013-05-13 17:00:00
```

How would I go about making this change? I have seen solutions to similar questions using temporary tables and variables that are very well suited to check for time differences but none that could be adapted (in my limited knowledge of MySQL queries) to my particular problem. I have also tagged this question as PHP because perhaps it would be simpler to do this in PHP.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `id` is the `Primary Key` of the table and it is `AUTO-INCREMENT`ing.

I have this `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE table T1
    SET T1.end_time = (
            SELECT T2.end_time
                FROM table T2
                WHERE T2.cid = T1.cid
                    AND T2.job_date = T1.job_date
                    AND T2.id > T1.id
                    AND T2.start_time <= DATE_ADD(T1.end_time, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
                ORDER BY T2.id ASC
                LIMIT 1
        )
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT T1.Id
            FROM table T1
            INNER JOIN table T2 ON T2.cid = T1.cid
                AND T2.job_date = T1.job_date
                AND T2.id > T1.id
                AND T2.start_time <= DATE_ADD(T1.end_time, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
            WHERE T1.job_date = @date
        );
```

It was a little complex though, and not that efficient. But since this is just a query, I think you will need to update the `end_time` every time (daily/weekly/etc).

And make sure you set the value for the `@date` variable, or you could just replace it with your desired date.

I'm thinking that using `CURSOR` (this is slow) will be more efficient than my query above.

Here is a sample `CURSOR` query:

```
DECLARE id INT(11);
DECLARE newEndDate DATETIME;

DECLARE noMoreRows BIT(1);
DECLARE customCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT T1.Id
        , CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(T2.start_date ORDER BY T2.Id ASC), ',', 1) AS DATETIME) AS NewEndDate
        FROM table T1
        INNER JOIN table T2 ON T2.cid = T1.cid
             AND T2.job_date = T1.job_date
             AND T2.id > T1.id
             AND T2.start_time <= DATE_ADD(T1.end_time, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
        WHERE T1.job_date = @date
        GROUP BY T1.Id
        HAVING NewEndDate <> '' OR NewEndDate IS NOT NULL;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET noMoreRows = 1;

OPEN customCursor;
customLoop: LOOP

    FETCH customCursor INTO id, newEndDate;

    IF noMoreRows THEN
      LEAVE customLoop;
   END IF;

    UPDATE table
        SET end_date = newEndDate
        WHERE id = id;

END LOOP customLoop;
CLOSE customCursor;
```

Just take note that `CURSOR` should be inside a `STORED PROCEDURE`. Here is the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) for `CURSORS`.

Comment: If you're going to use the `UPDATE` query, just test it first on a back-up table.

Comment: Thank you very much Kael! I will test it and let you know.

Comment: I get a query error "Column 'job_date' in where clause is ambiguous". I'm sure I will figure it out. In the meantime, I am reading up on CURSUR per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are formatting the start time and end time using php and then inserting into database table.

```
$start = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
$query = "select * from table name where cid = $cid and  UNIX_TIMESTAMP($start) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) <= 1800";
mysqli_query($con,$query);

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$query))
  {
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($rowcount > 1)
    { 
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

     query2 = "update tablename set end_time = '$start' where id = '$row['id']'";

     query3 = "insert into tablename(cid,date,start_time,end_time) values($cid,$date,$start,$end)";


    }else{

    //do the insert as such
    query2 = "insert into tablename(cid,date,start_time,end_time) values($cid,$date,$start,$end)";

    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks John! Your script compares the start/end times of one row. What I am having a hard time figuring out, in my example data, is how to compare the end time of row 3 against the start time of row 7. If the difference between 3.end and 7.start is less than 30 minutes (1800), then 3.end is updated with the value of 7.start. As you can see in my example query, although id is the primary key and is auto-incrementing (which confirms @KaeL's assumption), not all job entries are recorded sequentially, which is why I group them by consultant (cid) and then order them by start_time.

Comment: When a new entry is made, I am taking the start time(to be inserted) and finding the difference with already inserted `end_time`. The difference is found out for each rows which matches with cid(to be inserted). If a match is found with the 30 minutes(equal or less) difference, then the matching records `end_time` is updated with start time(to be inserted). Then later new entry is inserted. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation John! It makes more sense now! I wil try it out and let you know how it goes.